How to attempt problems which require squaring inequality with opposite signs
$$ \sqrt{5x-5} + \sqrt{3x+1} <  3 $$ simplifies to  $$x-7 < -3\sqrt{3x+1}$$ but I am unsure how to solve this further with certainty. If I square root both sides, I need to reverse the inequality sign, but it also creates extraneous solutions.

Hint: From the original inequality, you know immediately that $5x - 5 \geq 0,~$ and $~3x + 1 < 9.~$  So, for precisely which values of $~x~$ in the range $~\left[ ~1, \dfrac{8}{3} ~\right),~$ will the inequality hold?

Re last comment, I noticed that you did not add the pre-calculus tag.  Have you been taught about derivatives?  Assuming so, then if $$f(x) = \sqrt{5x-5} + \sqrt{3x + 1},$$ then what is $~f'(x),~$ and $~f''(x)?~$ Once you answer these two preliminary questions, you should be able to routinely examine the behavior of $~f(x)~$ on $$\left[ ~1, ~\frac{8}{3} ~\right).$$  Naturally, you will (also) need to manually compute both $~f(1)~$ and $~\displaystyle f\left( ~\frac{8}{3} ~\right).$

As $y=5x-5$ and $y=3x+1$ are both strictly increasing, we have that the LHS is strictly increasing as well. This means we can first solve for the LHS being equal to $3$. We have
\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{5x-5}+\sqrt{3x+1}\right)^2&=3^2\\
(5x-5)+(3x+1)+2\sqrt{(5x-5)(3x+1)}&=9\\
-8x+13&=2\sqrt{15x^2-10x-5}\\
(-8x+13)^2&=4(15x^2-10x-5)\\
64x^2-208x+169&=60x^2-40x-20\\
4x^2-168x+189&=0
\end{align}
By the quadratic equation and simplification, we have that $$x=21\pm\frac{15\sqrt7}{2}$$
However, in the original equation, the LHS has square roots, and the terms inside the square roots must be nonnegative. Solving the inequalities of $5x-5\geq 0$ and $3x+1\geq 0$ gives us $x\geq 1$. Also, as $\sqrt{5x-5}\geq 0$, we have that $\sqrt{3x+1}< 3$, which means $3x+1<9$ and $x<\frac83$.
This gives $$1\leq x<21-\frac{15\sqrt7}{2}$$ because the LHS is strictly increasing in the range $[1,\frac83)$ and $21+\frac{15\sqrt{7}}{2}$ will provide an undefined LHS.

Here is a straightforward calculation. For square roots to exist, we must have $x\ge1$. Assuming this, square both parts of $\sqrt{5x-5}+\sqrt{3x+1}\lt3$:
$$5x-5+3x+1+2\sqrt{(5x-5)(3x+1)}\lt 9$$
$$2\sqrt{(5x-5)(3x+1)}\lt13-8x.$$
This is equivalent to a system of two inequalities:
$$\begin{cases} 4 (5x-5)(3x+1)\lt (13-8x)^2\\ 13-8x\gt0.\end{cases}$$
Assuming that $1\le x\lt \frac{13}8$, let us solve the first inequality:
$$60x^2-40x-20\lt169-208x+64x^2$$
$$4x^2-168x+189\gt 0.$$
So, either $x\lt 21-\frac{15\sqrt 7}2$, or $x\gt 21+\frac{15\sqrt 7}2$. These numbers are ordered as follows:
$$1\lt 21-\frac{15\sqrt 7}2 \lt\frac{13}8 \lt 21+\frac{15\sqrt 7}2.$$
So the answer is $$1\le x\lt 21-\frac{15\sqrt 7}2.$$

@ultralegend5385 Sorry, your correction is wrong. $\sqrt{5x-5}$ only exists when $x\ge 1$. It does not exist for $0\le x <1$, as you suggest.

Yeah right, my bad I don't know what I was thinking.

Initially, I regarded the posting as low quality, with respect to MathSE protocol.  However, since there are now, two other answers, I will give my alternative approach, which is based on my comments.
You know immediately that $~5x - 5 \geq 0~$ and $~3x + 1 < 9.$
This implies that $~x \in \left[ ~1, ~\dfrac{8}{3} ~\right).$
Let $~\displaystyle f(x) = \sqrt{5x - 5} + \sqrt{3x + 1} \implies $

$\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac{5}{2\sqrt{5x-5}} + \frac{3}{2\sqrt{3x + 1}}.$

$\displaystyle f''(x) = \frac{-25}{2(5x-5)} 
+ \frac{-9}{2(3x + 1)}.$


So,

$f'(1) = +\infty.$

$\displaystyle f'(8/3) = \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{\frac{25}{3}}} + \frac{3}{2\sqrt{8 + 1} ~} > 0.~$

$\displaystyle \forall ~x \in \left[ ~1, ~\dfrac{8}{3} ~\right),  ~f''(x) < 0.~$


Therefore, $~\displaystyle \forall ~x \in \left[ ~1, ~\dfrac{8}{3} ~\right), ~f'(x) > 0.~$
This implies that $~\displaystyle \forall ~x \in \left[ ~1, ~\dfrac{8}{3} ~\right), ~f(x) ~$ is strictly increasing.

Further,

$f(1) = 2.$

$\displaystyle f(8/3) = \sqrt{\frac{25}{3}} + 3 > 3.$


Consequently, the entire problem reduces to identifying the unique value $~x_0 \in \left[ ~1, ~\dfrac{8}{3} ~\right) ~$ such that $~f(x_0) = 3.$
Note also, by the analysis in this answer, the value $~x_0~$ must exist, since $~f(x)~$ is a continuous function on the interval $~\left[ ~1, ~\dfrac{8}{3} ~\right).$
Then, based on the analysis in this answer, the final solution must be
$~[~1, ~x_0 ~).$

$$x \in \left[ ~1, ~\frac{8}{3} ~\right) 
~~\text{and} ~~f(x) = 3 \implies $$
$$\sqrt{5x - 5} = 3 - \sqrt{3x + 1} \implies $$
$$(5x - 5) = 9 + (3x + 1) - 6\sqrt{3x + 1} \implies $$
$$2x - 15 = -6\sqrt{3x + 1} \implies $$
$$4x^2 - 60x + 225 = 36(3x + 1) = 108x + 36 \implies $$
$$4x^2 - 168x + 189 = 0 \implies $$
$$x = \frac{1}{8} \left[ ~168 \pm \sqrt{168^2 - (16 \times 189) ~} ~\right] \implies $$
$$x = \frac{1}{8} \left[ ~168 \pm 4\sqrt{42^2 - 189 ~} ~\right] \implies $$
$$x = 21 \pm \frac{\sqrt{1764 - 189} ~}{2} = 21 \pm \frac{\sqrt{1575}~}{2} \implies $$
$$x = 21 \pm \frac{15\sqrt{7} ~}{2}.~$$
Since $~\displaystyle \sqrt{7} \approx 2.65,~$
you have that $\displaystyle ~\frac{15\sqrt{7}}{2} \approx 19.875.$
Therefore, since $~\displaystyle x_0 \in ~\left[ ~1, ~\dfrac{8}{3} ~\right), ~$ you have that
$$x_0 = 21 - \frac{15\sqrt{7} ~}{2},~$$
and the set of satisfying solutions is given by $~[ ~1, ~x_0).$
